# Log4j2 in Web application

Tags: java, web-applications, log4j2

How to configure Log4j2 with a simple java web application? I went through the tutorial in apache website but it did not give any straight forward examples w.r.t web applications. I used it in stand alone applications where I had static variables for loggers. But in Servlet, I think we cannot have instance variables. Should we use as static variable inside doPost ?

Also, any pointers to a configured log4j2 web app or tutorial with all the steps will be helpful as I am unable to find a right one.

I'm running on a Tomcat 6.0 server.

Answer (score 5):

**Servlets 3.0 environment**

It is such simple as to put `log4j2.xml` into `WEB-INF/classes`.

From [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)

> **The Short Story** 
>   Log4j 2 "just works" in Servlet 3.0 and newer web
>   applications. It is capable of automatically starting when the
>   application deploys and shutting down when the application undeploys.

**Servlets 2.5 environment**

> If you are using Log4j in a Servlet 2.5 web application, or if you
>   have disabled auto-initialization with the
>   isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled context parameter, you must
>   configure the Log4jServletContextListener and Log4jServletFilter in
>   the deployment descriptor or programmatically. The filter should match
>   all requests of any type. The listener should be the very first
>   listener defined in your application, and the filter should be the
>   very first filter defined and mapped in your application. This is
>   easily accomplished using the following web.xml code:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    <!-- Servlet 3.0 w/ disabled auto-initialization only; not supported in 2.5 -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Then write configuration options:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jContextName</param-name>
    <param-value>myApplication</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///etc/myApp/myLogging.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm beginner in web apps config. Do we need to create the classes folder ? I think it will not exist by default. Also, I'm using Tomcat 6.0 which I missed to mentioned earlier. Please suggest.

Comment: pity, tomcat 6 does not support servlets 3.0: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Yeah, but I am allowed to use only Tomcat 6. So I have to use servlet 2.5. I could not find a detailed tutorial on using log4j2 with web apps.

Comment: Classes are typically created automatically by build system or IDE during compilation.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Where do I write the configuration options ?

Comment: It all belongs to web.xml

Comment: @LeosLiterak how can one specify the value of "log4jConfiguration" manually? as, the file path could be dynamic depending on which location the war is deployed.

Comment: You should have asked week before. I could copy you source code where I did it the way that the value is taken from the environment. But I left the company.